# Communication without IP Address

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I want to ask about algorithm or method.  I have case like this:

I have application, I install it into 2 PC (different network), I want PC "A" can send data and read response from and to PC "B" but without knowing PC "B" IP Address.  And PC "B" can send data back to PC "B" without knowing PC "A" IP Address.

Example: PC "A" have unique application id => "ABC" and PC "B" have unique application id ==> "DDD"

How can I communicate / send data only using "ABC" or "DDD" as parameter?

example : PC "A" input PC "B" id ("DDD") to the text box, and send data. How can that data received by PC "B" or received by application that have id "DDD" ?

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) *"The only want I want is to use "Unique ID" that I generate from application"*  That makes no sense to me.  Can you rephrase it (use different words)?

Comment: You could always multicast.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Sorry for my bad english. I will try to rephrase it.

Comment: @vikingsteve : i don't think multicast is good solution, because that PC is from different network

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a Peer to Peer application.

There is the JXTA framework for this task. But AFAIK you will need some super peers if the 2 peers are in 2 different networks.

https://jxta.kenai.com/

The JXSE provides a Java implementation of JXTA.

https://jxse.kenai.com/

Note that the current status of the JXTA project is a bit unclear AFAIK.

Comment: i dont think JXSE is my solution, but i will try to analyze more about JXSE and JXTA

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to use some Messaging sytem like JMS. But in this case you may need an additional machine as the message broker and all machines must know (the IP address and port) of this broker.

In the early days there were also JMS implemantions without a central broker which used broadcast but I don't know if they still exist.